# how to remove rows with only one different column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table where for some rows, most of the columns are duplicated except for one column. I'm wondering how to select those rows and keep only one according to some requirements? Here's the table I have:

```
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| a_id | b_id | a_name | b_name  | matching  |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 001  | 123  |  AAA   |  BBB    |   ID      |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 002  | 456  |  CCC   |  CCC    |   ID      |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 002  | 456  |  CCC   |  CCC    |   Name    |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

The requirement is that for the same a_id, if there's both matching ID and matching Name, I want to remove the row with matching Name. The matching ID is determined by another table so we don't have to worry about that. so the desired output for the above table show be:

```
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| a_id | b_id | a_name | b_name  | matching  |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 001  | 123  |  AAA   |  BBB    |   ID      |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 002  | 456  |  CCC   |  CCC    |   ID      |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

I'm not very familiar with MySql. I'm thinking about using if statements to filter out the rows with the same a_id's first, then compare the matching column. But I'm not sure how that could be done in a query and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. 
I'll appreciate your inputs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only `matching` column is supposed to change?

Comment: no i'm obtaining this table by running a query which is looking into two tables and finding mathing ID and matching names. the problem is that some of them are overlapping (i.e. items with matching ids also have matching names)

Comment: Could you give us the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab because I had a sort-of similar problem which someone helped me with.  I may be over-complicating it though :)

I think the problem with just a plain group by a_id would be that you can't distinguish between 2 duplicates that have been grouped that nonetheless have different matching column values...

You'd just get;

```
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| a_id | b_id | a_name | b_name  | matching  |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 002  | 456  |  CCC   |  CCC    |   ID      |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

which you don't want to delete.  You want the dups with 'name' in the "matching" column right?

Possibly isolate the dups with your group-by a_id, but then isolate the results further to select those with the 'name' value in matching field?

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT * from MyTable alias1
inner join (select a_id from MyTable where matching = 'name') alias2 
on alias1.a_id = alias2.a_id
where matching = 'name'
```

if you leave out the "where matching = 'name'" you should get a list of all the dups to verify.
The full statement should return the following;

```
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| a_id | b_id | a_name | b_name  | matching  |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 002  | 456  |  CCC   |  CCC    |   name    |
+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

If the results match what you're aiming at you can then change the statement to delete.

Added this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34262/2/0)